# Realizar consulta Query Builder de Laravel

Tags: laravel, querybuilder

Necesito hacer una consulta SQL en query builder donde se combinan 3 tablas pero no se como hacerla, intente hacerlo de la siguiente forma, pero no me retorna nada. Siendo una de mis incógnitas el no saber si debo hacerla con joins en el Query Builder. Soy nuevo en esto, así que disculpen mi inexperiencia y gracias de antemano.

```
$invetario =  DB::table('items')
    ->select('id_item', 'nombre_item','subcategorias.id_subcategoria',
    'subcategorias.nombre_sub','categorias.id_categoria','categorias.nombre_cat')
    ->join('subcategorias','items.id_subcategoria','=','id_subcategoria')
    ->join('categorias','subcategorias.id_categoria','=','id_categoria')
    ->get;
```

Estas son mis tablas

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id_item` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre_item` varchar(191)  NOT NULL,
  `serial` varchar(191)  NOT NULL,
  `descripcion_item` varchar(191)  NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(191)  NOT NULL,
  `ubicacion` varchar(191)  NOT NULL,
  `A_cargo` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `id_subcategoria` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `subcategorias` (
  `id_subcategoria` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre_sub` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id_categoria` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre_cat` varchar(191)  NOT NULL
)
```

Y esta es la consulta que realice para mySql

```
SELECT id_item, nombre_item ,s.id_subcategoria, s.nombre_sub, c.id_categoria, c.nombre_cat
FROM items i, subcategorias s, categorias c 
WHERE i.id_subcategoria = s.id_subcategoria and c.id_categoria = s.id_categoria 
order BY id_item, id_subcategoria
```

Comment: ¿Y ese mismo join en mysql si retorna valores?

Comment: BetaM gracias por responder.
Si retorna valores

Comment: Mira al margen del error que tienes en el `get` deberías usar mejor llaves primarias y foráneas en tus entidades, esas columnas por ejemplo ya están indexadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debe pasar esto

```
$invetario =  DB::table('items')
    ->select('id_item', 'nombre_item','subcategorias.id_subcategoria',
    'subcategorias.nombre_sub','categorias.id_categoria','categorias.nombre_cat')
    ->join('subcategorias','items.id_subcategoria','=','id_subcategoria')
    ->join('categorias','subcategorias.id_categoria','=','id_categoria')
    ->get;
```

a esto

```
$inventario = DB::table('item as i')
->join ('subcategorias as sc','i.id_subcategoria','=','sc.id_subcategoria')
->join ('catagorias as c', 'sc.id_categoria','=','c.id_categoria')
->select('i.id_item','i.nombre_item','sc.id_subcategoria','sc.nombre_sub','c.id_categoria','c.nombre_cat')
->get();
```

adicionalmente a su codigo le falta () en el ->get